# Turn off printouts in bottle server

Tags: python, web-services

I am running a web server with the bottle package I got from bottlepy.org. I start the server with

```
run(host=localhost, port=8080, debug=False)
```

But the server keeps printing information on the screen whenever it gets a request. I need the server to not print anything in the terminal of which it is running.

Comment: why didn't you ask at Stack Overflow? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Comment: In my naivety I assumed people at programmers.stackexchange could answer questions about programming.

Comment: did you check [meta guidance](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773) referred in prior comment? "If your code or your IDE doesn't work, ask on..." etc